# Swift: Terminating app UITapGestureRecognizer for nib class

Tags: swift, xcode, nib

I create nib class :

```
import UIKit

class AlertController: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var back: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewMain: UIView!

    class func createAlert() -> AlertController {
        let myNib = UINib(nibName: "Alert", bundle: nil)
        let nib = myNib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! AlertController

        nib.back.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleBack(sender:))))

        return nib
    }

    @objc func handleBack(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //viewMain.isHidden = true
        print("LogIos => X")
    }
}
```

And use it on another class :

```
let view = AlertController.createAlert()
viewMain.addSubview(view)
```

This work fine, but if i click on `back button` i get below error:

> 2018-06-13 12:28:03.958448+0430 Mat[50493:243526] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[Mat.AlertController handleBackWithSender:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to class 0x104db4e90'

But if i use below code, work fine:

```
@IBAction func xxx(_ sender: Any) {
    print("LogIos => Y")
}
```

I want use `UITapGestureRecognizer` because i use `View` for custom button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do not understand what you mean with "`func xxx` works fine" (which should not, if you use the same code as above), the problem is that:

- `createAlert` is a static (`class`) function
- Inside

  - you create an instance `nib` of your `AlertController`
  - your `#selector` refers to `self`, which in this case is the *class* itself, not the instance
- Therefore, the gesture recognizer refers to the static (`class`) function `handleBack` - which you can see when you take a close look at `+` sign in the exception text:

  > reason: '+[Mat.AlertController handleBackWithSender:]: unrecognized selector
- Therefore, either make `handleBack` a static (`class func`), or provide an instance to as the target (which is what you want, as I would assume)

So

```
nib.back.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: nib, action: #selector(handleBack(sender:))))
```

should work for you.

### Remark

Nevertheless, let me allow you a design hint: Although you name it `AlertController`, it is not a view controller, but a `UIView` - this is confusing. You should clearly separate view and controller, and separate which of those handles what.